# Disable desktop text shadow in 18.04

Tags: 18.04, xfce, text

I upgraded from 16.04 to 18.04 and I noticed that desktop icons' text have shadows, which I dislike a lot. How can I disable the shadows? I attached some photos (16.04 vs 18.04), sorry for their quality.
Thanks.

[image: pic1]
[image: pic2]

Comment: What desktop do you running? Is it Xfce?

Comment: Yes, XFCE, I forgot to mention

Comment: I am using Numix, Greybird has the same problem...

Comment: Thanks @DKBose but it did not work, also the Numix in 18.04 is whiter than in 16.04, for example the Start menu is a light-grey instead of black...horrible.

Comment: Try Adwaita. It's present in a default Xubuntu 18.04 install. No shadows for text of icons on the desktop.

Comment: @DKBose The problem with Awaita is that the text is incapsulated in colored background: http://tinypic.com/r/mx2dew/9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the outset, I should point out that one reason for including shadows for text on the desktop is to ensure that the text is visible even if the user switches to a differently colored background or changes wallpapers. If the text is light, the shadow is dark. So, with a light background, the shadow ensures some legibility at least if the actual text is also light.

---

In what follows, I'm using a plain background similar to the ones in the question with Greybird as the theme on Xubuntu 18.04.1.

This image has text with shadows:

[image: text with shadows]

In the next image, shadows are removed:

[image: text without shadows]

To remove the shadows, one has to edit Greybird's *gtkrc* file. I first copied the entire Greybird folder from */usr/share/themes* over to *~/.themes* which I created in my home folder. To distinguish the copied local version from the system one, I renamed the local version *MyGreybird*.

In *~/.themes/MyGreybird/gtk-2.0/gtkrc*, the code determining the appearance of text on the desktop is in the section titled 
*style "xfcedesktop-icon-view"* (~ line 927). To remove shadows, I commented out all lines relating to shadows. (These lines are not commented out in the original *gtkrc*.)

```
style "xfdesktop-icon-view"
{
    XfdesktopIconView::label-alpha = 0
    XfdesktopIconView::selected-label-alpha = 80
#   XfdesktopIconView::shadow-x-offset = 0
#   XfdesktopIconView::shadow-y-offset = 1
#   XfdesktopIconView::selected-shadow-x-offset = 0
#   XfdesktopIconView::selected-shadow-y-offset = 1
#   XfdesktopIconView::shadow-color = shade(1.5, @tooltip_bg_color)
#   XfdesktopIconView::selected-shadow-color = shade(1.8, @tooltip_bg_color)
#   XfdesktopIconView::shadow-blur-radius = 2
    XfdesktopIconView::cell-spacing = 2
    XfdesktopIconView::cell-padding = 6
    XfdesktopIconView::cell-text-width-proportion = 1.9

    fg[NORMAL] = shade (0.9, @selected_fg_color)
    fg[ACTIVE] = @selected_fg_color
```

Removing shadows is fine provided one has a simple darkish background. With lighter backgrounds or wallpapers, text legibility maybe reduced. *File System* and *Home* are virtually invisible in the image below.

[image: text with shadows on a light background]

---

One could also play with

```
XfdesktopIconView::label-alpha = 0
XfdesktopIconView::selected-label-alpha = 80
```

to increase or decrease the transparency of the region surrounding text such as surrounding *Trash* in the last image.

---

Note that even though Greybird is a compiled theme, that only affects the gtk3 aspect. In 18.04, Xubuntu still has a gtk2-based desktop and so the gtk2 aspects can be modified without much difficulty.

Answer (score 0):

In 2021 DK Boses answer does not work anymore. You can now do it the following way:

Put the following into `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css` (This is the default file for user modifications of GTK 3 display themes):

```css
.label {
    text-shadow:none;
    color:black;      /* Font color. */
}
```

Restart.

Result:

[image]

More inspiration: [Fedora 33 XFCE default theme css](https://fossies.org/linux/gtk/gtk/theme/Adwaita/Adwaita.css)